# C++ syntax question

Tags: c++, coding-style

I'm working on a UDP based file-sharing program. Let me post some sample code before explain the problem.

```
while (true) 
{
    Data toRecv;
    int bytesRead = recvfrom(s->_UPDsock, (char*)&toRecv, sizeof(toRecv), 0,(SOCKADDR*)&remoteAddress, &remoteAddresslength);
    if(bytesRead > 0)
    {
        string temp(toRecv.chunk,(bytesRead-sizeof(int)));
        if(!checker)
        {
            //total packet amount.
            totalChunkAmount = toRecv.ACK;
            checker = true;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see at line "13" I'm initializing the `totalChunkAmount` by using the variable I got from UDP's `recvFrom` function. I need to initialize that value only ONCE, that's why I'm using it inside a `bool` `if()` check. and after the initialization, I'm flipping the `bool` value to `true`, so it will not be initialized again. Is there any other way to achieve the same result, but not using the ugly `bool` switching method.

Comment: Note that this is probably a bad idea. UDP packets may be lost or arrive out of order. You should probably use TCP instead.

Comment: @Billy: yes, that may be very true, but his question didn't really have to do with anything UDP or TCP after all...

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that's why it's a comment rather than an answer :)

Comment: That's not a syntax question at all.

Comment: @Luc, you are right. Retagged (and reformatted) the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `totalChunkAmount` to an invalid state before it's initialized and check for that state. For example if `totalChunkAmount` is an `int` then,

```
totalChunkAmount = -1; // say -1 is invalid value
while(true)
{
 ...
 if(-1 == totalChunkAmount)
   totalChunkAmount = toRecv.ACK; // ACK can never be -1
}
```

Likewise, if `totalChunkAmount` is a pointer then you may set it to `NULL` (`0`).

[Edit Note: I am just wondering, in your `while` loop mainly you are initializing variable then why don't your `break` out of the loop after that ? If you can do so it's lot more cleaner and no such checks are needed.]

Comment: Thanks a lot. it looks way better and 4 lines shorter.

Answer (score 1):

```
totalChunkAmount = totalChunkAmount == [uninitialized_value_here] ? toRecv.ACK : totalChunkAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of off hand would be to initialize totalChunkAmount to -1 (or some other non real world value) and then check for that (avoiding the additional bool declaration).

Answer (score 0):

The code that you proposed is maybe longer, but surely **more readable** and makes it easier to follow the logic, and I would just leave it as is.

The only change I'd do is to rename the faceless `bool checker` to `bool totalChunkAmountInitialized`.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is to use boost::optional<>. It's perfect for such cases and fairly lightweight. If you can't or don't want to use boost:: you can code your own similar class fairly easily.